# viewing the contents of a file as decimal numbers format using vi

Tags: format, decimal, vi

I am saving audio input in a file called sound.raw by using **alsa api**. I think that the sound amplitudes are being saved (it is a guess, i am not sure). The format i use is **signed 16 bit number little endian** (S16_LE). Now if the amplitudes are being saved, how do i see the amplitudes in **decimal number format** because as of now i only see a collection of @s and ^s and various other symbols which aren't making sense when i open the sound.raw file with vi.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the binary representation of the sound data as interpreted by vi (probably as ASCII). However, it is not meant to be human-readable, or a lot of storage would be wasted.

See [Using vi as a hex editor](http://www.linuxinstead.com/blog/2009/04/21/using-vi-as-a-hex-editor/) for a way to show the data in [hexadecimal format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), which is the closest you're going to get to an answer to your question without (writing your own) specific software for displaying ALSA-formatted sound data in a human-readable fashion.